# Dotted lines in GTK3 Theme

Tags: linux, gnome, gtk

I recently tried the Vertex Theme, you can get it [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Vertex+-+Theme?content=166318) in case you are interested. It looks very decent in my opinion, except for the dotted lines in windows using GTK3. As they seem to be for visual debugging, how can i disable them?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the correct version.

GTK3 theming has been reworked substantially over the past few releases, so a theme written for GTK 3.10 won't work correctly with 3.14 and vice versa.

According to the theme's description, it has multiple versions included, and you have to install the correct one.